# Trying to submit data using put on axios but got 405 method not allowed

Tags: jquery, axios, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to submit using PUT method in the jquery code

```
  $('#mainTable td').on('change', function(evt, newValue) {
    var $put_method = $('#user-put-method input').val();
    var $name       = $(this).attr('id');
    var $url        = "<?php echo route('Profile.update', Auth::id()) ?>";
    var data        = {
      '__method': $put_method,
      'name': $name
    };

    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
    axios.post($url, data)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
```

and the data source for this `var $put_method = $('#user-put-method input').val();` is from

```
<div class="" id="user-put-method">
  {{ method_field('PUT') }}
</div>
```

and I have this method to catch the request

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  d($request, $id);
}
```

and through this route

```
Route::resource('Profile', 'UserProfileController');
```

But when I look at chrome dev-tool
I got this message

```
http://project.dev/Profile/1 405 method not allowed
```

Does anyone encounter or did similar to my problem?

Comment: Instead of Route::resource, try Route::Put, depending on your request type. Also, the url isn't exactly correct, you should follow the same format. It says Profile/1, so you would need to either recognize the /1 as a different route or a variable  --  Route::resource('Profile/{id}', 'UserProfileController');   or similar, but try these options. I've had this issue before and it was related to the HTTPVerb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On you HTML header file add this script:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        'base_url'  => \URL::to('/'),
    ]); ?>
</script>
```

And your axios data :

```
var data        = {
  '__method': $put_method,
  'name': $name,
  '_token': window.Laravel.csrfToken
}; 
// axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

  axios.put($url, data)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```